# Calculating object rotation based on plane normal

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, lwjgl

I am currently working on procedurally generated terrain using simplex noise and the marching cubes algorithm. I've completed the process of creating a ground mesh which different entities like plants will lie on. However the models rendered will always point upwards instead of the direction which the trianglular face they lie on is pointing. This renders them into the ground which does not look good. I have already calculated the normals of each triangle so I am wondering how I would convert the normal of the triangular face to a 3D XYZ rotation for the model.

The image below shows my current problem:

**Clipped plant models**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to construct a rotation matrix from each normal?

Comment: Do you need the XYZ rotation angles or would you be happy with the rotation matrix?

Comment: @Joni the rotation matrix would be good but I am also fine with XYZ rotation angles.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the cross product of up vector with plane normal. That will give you the rotation axis. Then take the dot product of the up vector with plane normal, that will give you the cosine of the rotation angle. So you have:

```
Axis = normalize(cross(up, normal))

Angle = acos(dot(up, normal))
```

Then you can construct a quaternion or a rotation matrix from axis and angle.

See:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToQuaternion/index.htm